# Destroying session for user login / NULL $_SESSION remnant

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm trying to create a user login system for use on a website I'm building. I have the login script and register script, but I'm having trouble with the logout and destroying the sessions.

Here's my index code. It gets the database info in config (doesn't do anything with it yet), then runs check-login to make sure the user is actually logged in. It has a logout button that routes to logout.php

```
<?php 
    include_once("config.php");
    include_once("check-login.php");
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
?>

<html>
<body>
    <h1>
        Hello <? echo $username ?>! We're still building, but feel free to... wait?
    </h1>
    <form action="logout.php">
        <input class="logoutbutton" type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my check-login.php file. Notice that anytime I link back to the index, I'm using a `$_GET` to post some information into the address bar. There is no place where I simply go back to `index.php`

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include_once("../myreadingplanner_config/config.php");

    if(($_SESSION['username']) != null){ //If user is already logged in...
        $username=$_SESSION['username'];
        header("Location: index.php?Message=AlreadyLoggedIn$username");
    } 
    else {

        if(isset($_POST['username']) && strlen($_POST['username'])!=0){ //if username is valid
            $username = $_POST['username'];
        } else {
            header('Location: login.php');
        }

        if(isset($_POST['password']) && strlen($_POST['password'])!=0){
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        } else {
            header('Location: login.php');
        }

        $SQLString = "SELECT TOP(1) * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQLString) or die ("");

        if($result != null)
        {   
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: index.php?Message=YouLoggedIn$username");
        } else {
            header("Location: index.php?Message=UserLoginNotFound&Username=$username");
    }
}
ob_flush();
?>
```

And finally here is my logout.php, which should (in theory) destroy the session, and head back to index.php. When it gets back to index.php, index.php will reroute to login.php using the `include_once("check-login.php");`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Just looking at my logic, there SHOULD be an infinite loop in the check-login, right? Because if the user is logged in, it should reroute to index, which includes check-login, which reroutes to index, which... etc.

If you want to check out the site for yourself, please go to www.myreadingplanner.com, and use this info to login (user will be deleted eventually)

```
Username: StackUser
Password: password1
```

So functionality wise, login.php should NEVER be visible unless you have a valid session, and when it does, it should say 'Welcome $username!'. But if you hit the logout button on index, it will still keep the session open, but it will be null.

Any advice on either why logout doesn't seem to fully logout the user OR why it is logging the user out but is keeping the NULL $_SESSION around?

Comment: Well first you should check if the session isset for username on your index. Also try unset($_SESSION['session_var']);

Comment: I had heard that using `unset($_SESSION['username']);` was for an older version of PHP and shouldn't be used anymore. I'll give it a try anyways. As for checking if the session isset, that should be handled in the included check-login.php, right?

Comment: I always practice never trust anything lol. So a simple if condition with an exit won't hurt. The only thing I've read about unset is not to unset the global arrays altogether. Like $_SESSION or $_COOKIE not sure how much it would conflict but I always do the sessions that need to be unset anyways.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Alright I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Sounds good doesn't hurt to try anyways. From there if that doesn't work we'll figure it out.

Comment: Dude, you're awesome. That worked - there was also an issue where I was calling session_start() at the wrong time. But everything is working now!! Last question --- can you mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: No but I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove sessions use

```
unset($_SESSION['SESSION_VAR'] );
session_destroy(); //closes the session and prevents session riding
```

For more information I'd research session riding as you should close your session as soon as you can to prevent this.

Also do not unset the entire session global array.

```
//don't do this
unset($_SESSION);
```

Comment: `foreach($k in \array_keys($_SESSION)) { \unset($_SESSION[$k]); }` :)

Comment: Yeah I wasn't going to post this just because sometimes this isn't the needed case. Thanks though for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

First, have a look at index.php file. in that file, change the code below:

```
include_once("config.php");
include_once("check-login.php");
session_start(); // move the session_start function and place at the top of the script
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
```

change it, so that it becomes like this:

```
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
include_once("check-login.php");
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
```

This problem occurs because at the file check-login.php you do not declare the function session_start();

I have tested this problem. And it works!